# Negative margin with mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I want to get the size of current user browser, and center the header based on half of the size.
**(With Mootools)**

*css*

```
#header{position:absolute; left:50%; }
```

*Javascript*

```
var width = $(document.body).getStyle('width');
var margin = width/2;

$('header').setStyles({'width': width, 'margin-left': -(margin.toInt())});
```

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like it's setting the width to the full width of the body? So why center it if it's just going to be full width?

Comment: Because it is a position absolute element...

Comment: @GabrielSantos May I ask why you're using JavaScript to accomplish this? CSS will allow you to center an element just as you describe. If you'd like, I can provide that CSS.

Comment: Yes, but if a 1024px monitor have 1024px, so, margin-left should be -512px. If my resolution is 2000px, margin-left should be -1000, and so on. CSS can't do this, because is "static".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that `setStyle` for some properties can take a number (and will add the units to it), or it will just use the string you give it. Since you are giving it a string, by prepending `'-'+...` it will create the CSS `margin-left:-34` without the unit. You can either give it a number, or add the unit yourself. Additionally, you need to make sure width is a number before you divide by 2 (as getStyle will return a string with 'px')

```
var width = $(document.body).getStyle('width');
var margin = width.toInt()/2;

$('header').setStyle('margin-left', -(margin.toInt()));
// or
$('header').setStyle('margin-left', '-'+margin.toInt()+'px');
```

After you answered my question above, I'll remark that you can accomplish this w/o javascript or negative margins if `#header` is supposed to be positioned at the top of the screen, at a full width (and not within a relatively positioned element):

```
#header {position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%;}
```

Comment: Worked fine! I don't understand why I have forgot this.. need a coffe =)